# Header image is getting covered by Bootstrap 's menu

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

The image is getting covered by the menu even when I add the CSS code to give it a space. Then I just have a blue space above my menu but no image. I get a flash like it is loading it and then covering it.

```
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="media/Journey_To_The_Stars728x90.png" class="img-circle" alt="Journey To The Stars!" width="728" height="90">
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Home</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Systems <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Stars 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Planets 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Moons 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS bit

```
body {
    padding-top: 90px;
    background-color: #aabbcc;
}
```

edit
I just added some more code in case the error is there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Journey To The Stars</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
    <div class="container">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer!

Adblock Plus was blocking the picture. Now I need to learn why...

Edit:

Now I know why. It blocks "728x90". I added that to the name because my research showed it was the most common header picture size. Must be the most common ad size as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is even after adding the `padding: 90px;` to the body, the header will be rendered after it, so you achieved nothing unless you use `absolute` positioning for example, try the snippet below:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 90px;
  background-color: #aabbcc;
}
header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="media/Journey_To_The_Stars728x90.png" class="img-circle" alt="Journey To The Stars!" width="728" height="90">
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Home</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Systems <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Stars 1-1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Planets 1-2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Moons 1-3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Assuming that the only thing you added or changed was the css header stuff then your idea did not work.

Comment: Is your image only 90px?

Comment: Yes. It is 728x90 png.

Comment: If that is the case then the code above should work, at least it is working in the snippet. If you need more help,  show me the result in a Screenshot, and I will try to see what is going on?

Comment: It is still not working. A added the base code. You can see the website here sometimes, when my computer is on. 192.168.2.102 Image is http://192.168.2.102/media/Jouney_To_The_Stars728x90.png

Comment: Kindly update the question to contain one HTML section with everything in its original place.

Comment: It is all in it's original place. The first code bit is the nav.php the second in the css and the third is the index.php (and all the other pages are the same at the top). I cut out the text bits after the menu (nav) include.